# Attempt to write jQuery fadeTo effect in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onhover

A Website uses only one single jQuery function which we'd like to replace by an equal pure Javascript function. However I struggle to convert (translate) that function. 
I am aware jQuery is perfect for that task but the trade-off to download all jQuery code for the few lines of Javascript might be worth the effort - in which I do not succeed.

**What the script is doing**:
When hovering a sectionBox the all other sectionBox(es) fadeTo a value of 0.4.
The script does NOT utilize IDs assigned to each SectionBox.

The question is: How to handle the equivalent of children and siblings in Javascript?

**Update:**
After doing some homework I came up with some own functional code which is far from the final Goal to achieve equal functionality and smooth transitions, but at least in its functionality comparable to the existing function in the jQuery code.
Also I rephrased the question(s).

A really great solution using CSS only was provided to solve the problem. However I'd like to learn whether and how I can solve this in pure Javascript.

Currently there are three columns. Left and Center columns are affected by my homework-code whereas the column to the right uses the original jQuery code.

May I suggest to look at the example below to visualize the anticipated Goal.

Here are few **Questions**:

**Q1**: How can the functions be combined into less and more efficient functions?
So that hovering an element encompasses all elements in the three columns.

Running the code in Codepen one can observe that when leaving a column (left or center) the last item hovered remains with a value of low opacity.
**Q2**: How can this behaviour be controlled?

```js
/* --- code to convert ---*/
/*hover left column*/
/*$("#left").children().hover(function() {
  $(this).siblings().stop().fadeTo(300,0.4);
  $('#center > .sectionBox').stop().fadeTo(300,0.4);
  $('#right > .sectionBox').stop().fadeTo(300,0.4);
}, 
function() {
  $(this).siblings().stop().fadeTo(200,1);
  $('#center > .sectionBox').stop().fadeTo(200,1);
  $('#right > .sectionBox').stop().fadeTo(200,1);
});
*/

/* --- attempt to convert jQuery code from above ---*/
/* --- currently affecting left- and center-columns only --- */
/* --- How to combine functions into less and more efficient functions */
/*
var elem_IDLft = 'left'
var elem_IDCtr = 'center'
var elem_IDRgt = 'right'
*/
/* --- LEFT Column ---*/
var elemLft_ID = 'left'
var elemL_name = document.getElementById(elemLft_ID).children;
var elemL_length = elemL_name.length;

for (var i=0; i<elemL_length; i++) {
  elemL_name[i].addEventListener("mouseover", mouseOverL);
  elemL_name[i].addEventListener("mouseout", mouseOutL);
}
/*---mouse events---*/
/*---Don't use: style.display = "none"--*/
//function mouseOver() {this.style.opacity = "1.0";}
//function mouseOut() {this.style.opacity = "0.4";}

function mouseOverL() {
  for (var i=0; i<elemL_length; i++) {
    if (elemL_name[i] === this) {elemL_name[i].style.opacity = "1.0";} 
  else {elemL_name[i].style.opacity = "0.5";}
  }
  return;
}

function mouseOutL() {
  for (var i=0; i<elemL_length; i++) {
    if (elemL_name[i] !== this) {elemL_name[i].style.opacity = "1.0";} 
  else {elemL_name[i].style.opacity = "0.5";}
  }
  return;
}

// --- To-Do: smooth Transitions

/* --- CENTER Column ---*/
var elemCtr_ID = 'center'
var elem_name = document.getElementById(elemCtr_ID).children;
var elem_length = elem_name.length;

for (var i=0; i<elem_length; i++) {
  elem_name[i].addEventListener("mouseover", mouseOver);
  elem_name[i].addEventListener("mouseout", mouseOut);
}
/*---mouse events---*/
/*---Don't use: style.display = "none"--*/
//function mouseOver() {this.style.opacity = "1.0";}
//function mouseOut() {this.style.opacity = "0.4";}

function mouseOver() {
  for (var i=0; i<elem_length; i++) {
    if (elem_name[i] === this) {elem_name[i].style.opacity = "1.0";} 
  else {elem_name[i].style.opacity = "0.5";}
  }
  return;
}

function mouseOut() {
  for (var i=0; i<elem_length; i++) {
    if (elem_name[i] !== this) {elem_name[i].style.opacity = "1.0";} 
  else {elem_name[i].style.opacity = "0.5";}
  }
  return;
}

/* --- Question: How to properly get the inverse for the above 'this' ?---*/
/* --- So that the element 'this' (hovered) has style.opacity = 1 ---*/
/* --- and all others from elem_name get style.opacity = 0.4 --- */
/* --- At the moment it's really bumpy --- */
/* --- Possibly caused by many forced reflows while executing Javascript occur --- */
/* --- The goal is to obtain smooth transitions ---*/

/*-------------------------------------*/
/*--- more jQuery code for columns 'center' and 'right' ---*/
/*--- center column*/
/*
$("#center").children().hover(function() {
  $(this).siblings().stop().fadeTo(300,0.4);
  $('#left > .sectionBox').stop().fadeTo(300,0.4);
  $('#right > .sectionBox').stop().fadeTo(300,0.4);
}, 
function() {
  $(this).siblings().stop().fadeTo(200,1);
  $('#left > .sectionBox').stop().fadeTo(200,1);
  $('#right > .sectionBox').stop().fadeTo(200,1);
});
*/
/*--- right column*/
$("#right").children().hover(function() {
  $(this).siblings().stop().fadeTo(300,0.4);
  $('#center > .sectionBox').stop().fadeTo(300,0.4);
  $('#left > .sectionBox').stop().fadeTo(300,0.4);
}, 
function() {
  $(this).siblings().stop().fadeTo(200,1);
  $('#center > .sectionBox').stop().fadeTo(200,1);
  $('#left > .sectionBox').stop().fadeTo(200,1);
});
```

```css
/*liquid display*/
body {font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:62.5%;}
html {font-size:10px; color:#fff; background-color:#242424;}

#wrapper {width: 100%;font-size: 1.2rem; overflow: hidden}
.column {float: left; width: 31.0%; margin-right: 3.5%;} /* 100%-(3*31%)=7%/2=3.5%*/
.last {margin-right: 0;}

h1 {font-size: 1.2rem; text-align:center;padding:-1rem;}
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {#left.column, #center.column, #right.column {width: 100%;}}

.sectionBox {
background-color: rgba(100,100,100,1.0);
box-shadow: 5px 5px 7px #111;
margin: 0 0 2.0rem 0;
padding: 0.1rem;
}

.sectionBox > p > code {background-color:#efefef; color:#111;}

#left {color:#fffaaa;}
#center {color:#fffccc;}
#right {color:#fffeee;}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="sectionBox"><h1>Flexbox - fadeTo - transition: from jQuery to pure Javascript</h1>
    <p><strong>An attempt to translate this jQuery 'fadeTo'-function to pure Javascript.</strong>
      <br />
      <code>
    /*hover left column*/<br>
$("#left").children().hover(function() {
  $(this).siblings().stop().fadeTo(300,0.4);
  $('#center > .sectionBox').stop().fadeTo(300,0.4);
  $('#right > .sectionBox').stop().fadeTo(300,0.4);
}, 
function() {
  $(this).siblings().stop().fadeTo(200,1);
  $('#center > .sectionBox').stop().fadeTo(200,1);
  $('#right > .sectionBox').stop().fadeTo(200,1);
});      
    </code>
    </p>
</div>
  
  <div id="left" class="column">id="left"
    <section class="sectionBox"><h1>id="newPictures"</h1>
  </section>
    <section class="sectionBox"><h1>id="oldPictures"</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="sectionBox"><h1>id="somePlace"</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="sectionBox"><h1>id="someOtherPlace"</h1>
  </section>
 </div>

  <div id="center" class="column">id="center"
  <section class="sectionBox"><h1>id="travelNews"</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="sectionBox"><h1>id="otherTravelNews"</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="sectionBox"><h1>id="impressum"</h1>
  </section>
 </div>

  <div id="right" class="column last">id="right"
  <section class="sectionBox"><h1>id="search"</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="sectionBox"><h1>id="toolsFaq"</h1>
  </section>
 </div>
</div> <!--.wrapper-->
```

This is the working example of the relevant jQuery code.

```
/*hover left column*/
$("#left").children().hover(function() {
  $(this).siblings().stop().fadeTo(300,0.4);
  $('#center > .sectionBox').stop().fadeTo(300,0.4);
  $('#right > .sectionBox').stop().fadeTo(300,0.4);
}, 
function() {
  $(this).siblings().stop().fadeTo(200,1);
  $('#center > .sectionBox').stop().fadeTo(200,1);
  $('#right > .sectionBox').stop().fadeTo(200,1);
});

/*hover center column*/
/*same function for "#center" and "#right" columns*/
```

... and here is the same code over at codepen.
[Link to Codepen](https://codepen.io/snahl/pen/mpNbrw)

Comment: Extract and copy paste the relevant code from jQuery, and viola - you have cross browser fadeTo without jQuery ...

Comment: Note that jQuery is a JavaScript library so yes it should be possible.

Comment: @davidkonrad - Sorry, I don't get it. What exactly do you mean by 'extract and copy-paste'. Code is here, extract what from where, then copy to where? I'm puzzled.

Comment: @snahl check the answer bellow, no need to use any javascript for this one ;)

Comment: @facundo-forradini - the function affects at least 2 DIVs pointed out in the question:  When hovering a sectionBox the all other sectionBox(es) fadeTo a value of 0.4.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Element.animate()`

```js
const div = document.getElementById("animate");

div.onclick = () => {
  div.animate({
      opacity: 0
    }, {
      duration: 1000,
      easing: "linear",
      iterations: 1,
      fill: "both"
    })
    .onfinish = function() {     
      console.log(div.style.opacity);         
    }
}
```

```css
#animate {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
  color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div id="animate">click</div>
```

Comment: @AngelPolitis What is the result when launching Chrome with `--enable-experimental-web-platform-features` flag, either by first closing all running instances of Chrome or also setting `--user-data-dir` flag to a configuration folder other than the running instance of Chrome?

Comment: By enabling the `--enable-experimental-web-platform-features` flag it works, so you've earned my upvote! But still, its rather useless to the OP or any production website at this time, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need jQuery for that... and you don't even need javascript either.

pure CSS will do:

```css
/*liquid display*/
body {font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:62.5%;}
html {font-size:10px; color:#fff; background-color:#242424;}
#wrapper {overflow: hidden; width: 100%;}
.column {float: left; width: 31.0%; margin-right: 3.5%;} /* 100%-(3*31%)=7%/2=3.5%*/
.last {margin-right: 0;}
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {#left.column, #center.column, #right.column {width: 100%;}}

.sectionBox {
font-size: 1.6rem;
background-color: rgba(100,100,100,1.0);
box-shadow: 5px 5px 7px #111;
margin: 0 0 1.5rem 0;
padding: 0.5rem 0.3rem 0.5rem 0.3rem;
opacity:1; /* set initial opacity and transition time*/
transition:opacity 200ms ease; /*for when hover-out*/
}

#left {color:#fffaaa;}
#center {color:#fffccc;}
#right {color:#fffeee;}


#wrapper{
  pointer-events: none; /*prevents the :hover from firing*/
}                       /*when not actually on an item */
.sectionBox{
  pointer-events:auto; /*resets the hover on the items */
}
#wrapper:hover .sectionBox{
  opacity:0.4; /*when hovering the container, all items becomes translucent*/
  transition: opacity 300ms ease;
}

#wrapper:hover .sectionBox:hover{
  opacity:1; /*prevents the specific hovered item opacity from changing*/
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"> 
 <div id="left" class="column">
  <section class="sectionBox"> id="newPictures"
  </section>
  <section class="sectionBox"> id="oldPictures"
  </section>
  <section class="sectionBox"> id="somePlace"
  </section>
 </div>
 <div id="center" class="column">
  <section class="sectionBox"> id="travelNews"
  </section>
  <section class="sectionBox"> id="impressum"
  </section>
 </div>

 <div id="right" class="column last">
  <section class="sectionBox"> id="search"
  </section>
  <section class="sectionBox"> id="toolsFaq"
  </section>
 </div>
</div>
```

The trick is to use the hover on the container to adjust the opacity of all the childs, while setting the pointer-events to none so it won't fire when not actually over a child. 
Then it's just using the hover on the specific child to reset the opacity to 1, and adjusting the transitions.

100% pure CSS magic FTW!

Comment: Great and Thanks! That works just fine. I am using this same method for my menus on my website, but I was not aware of the CSS pointer-events: encompassing elements higher up in the hierarchy. It's not the direct answer to my question(s), but its a really great solution, serves the purpose and solves the problem that lead to my question. So I give you the upvote. However I did quite a bit of homework and would be curious to learn how to achieve the same in pure Javascript.